# Database First Error Entity Framework .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am converting an old Class Library to a Class Library Package. This Class Library is the DAL Layer of an old project - which we will be upgrading to latest .NET.

In the old Class Library we are using `edmx` files for Database first. In the new .NET the support for edmx has stopped, but we still need to generate the Model from the Database - Because the database is already in place.

For this I am following the Steps provided in this link: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

So what I have done is created a new Class Library Package:

[image]

And the project.json is this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "xPT.DAL Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Dawood" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11",
        "System.Linq": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

Now when I install: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, as mentioned in the Link above, I get this error:

Using this command : `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

[image]

The Error List:

[image]

It says here:

```
The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 1.0.0 in project xPT.DAL does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6
```

But according to the documentation, this library should be supported for all above `4.5.1`: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/sql-server/index.html#supported-platforms

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seem to be the caching is still only working with"dnx-XXX" .NET Framework: if you want to use these packages in your own project, remove net46 and add a new dnx46 TFM and it should work.

Comment: @BassamAlugili still the same errors: The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 1.0.0 in project xPT.DAL does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay it took me about a day to figure it out so here I am posting the steps I followed to get my Database First working in a `Class Project (.NET Core)`, with a .NET Core Web App.

## Step 1 - Install .NET Core

Make Sure you are using .NET Core not DNX `(Hint: You should be able to see the .NET Core option when creating a New Project)` - If NOT Download from [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/net)

If you have problems installing .NET Core (Error is something like Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 not installed correctly) - You can run the installing using the command: [`DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`] -- Which will prevent the installation performing the Visual Studio Check [Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1626)

[image]

## Step 2 - Create The Projects

Create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application --> Then Select Web Application in the next screen

[image]

Add a `Class Library (.NET Core)` Project

[image]

## Step 3 - Installing EF Packages

Open your `project.json` file of Class Library, and paste the following, then Save the file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should restore the packages under `References`

[image]

### ---------------- OR

You can install them using Nuget Package Manager by running the following commands in the Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

Note: Install one Package at a time - if you get an error after installing

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Then change the content of your `project.json` frameworks section to this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

## Step 4 - Creating the Database Model

Now to generate the Database run the following command in the `Package Manager Console` (DON'T forget to Change the connection string to your Database)

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=. ; Database=DATABASE; user id= USER ; password = PASSWORD;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

This will give you the Error about Startup Project:

[image]

For this you have to add the same references you added to Class Library to the .NET Web App

So open your `project.json` for the Web App,

Under `dependencies`, add:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

and under `tools` add:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

After making the changes Save the file.

This is what my project.json looks like

[image]

Then again run the command in Package Manager Console against the class library:

If you haven't already added the reference of your Class Library to the Web App, you will get this error:

[image]

to solve this add reference of your class Library to your Web App:

[image]

## Finally

Run the Command again - in the `Package Manager Console`:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=. ; Database=DATABASE; user id= USER ; password = PASSWORD;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

This should create the Entities under Models Folder, in the class library

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:
Looks like you're still using DNX. Please upgrade to .NET Core (along with .NET CLI) as DNX is no longer supported. You can download .NET Core [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net).

---

`net46` is a Target Framework Moniker (TMF) for desktop .NET framework 4.6. You don't need to reference packages such as `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.Collections` on that framework since they are part of the full .NET framework by default. You only need  those when targeting a .NET Standard version such as `netstandard1.6`.

Remove all the depdendencies you listed under `net46`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error when I install : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: The project.json in my answer works on an empty class library. Do you have any other dependencies?

Comment: No - It is a new Class Library Package, with no classes at the moment - You can see the entire project in the image I shared in the question

Comment: Do you think this is because of the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Version?

Comment: I understand. I created a test project (.NET Core Class Library (Package)) and it works.

Comment: No, Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I also tried creating a new Class Library Package in a new solution but I still get the same error

Comment: @DawoodAwan: please stop using DNX. It's over 9 months old and not maintained anymore. .NET core moved to dotnet-cli with RC2 and RTM is already there since 1 1/2 months!

Comment: Ah now I see. You're indeed still using DNX. Please download .NET Core from [here](http://dot.net) and start using  that.

Answer (score 2):

## !!!!Stop using DNX!!!!

[ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 did already hit RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/announcing-net-core-1-0/) 1 1/2 months ago.

DNX is unsupported **and not maintained** since RC2!

You must be using RC1 or older, because its the last DNX build.

The RTM versions of the packages don't work with RTM! Uninstall your (ASP).NET 5 Tools and install [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) from Microsoft page.